# How do I create deb package for Oracle JDK?

Tags: java, packaging

How do I create a deb package for Oracle JDK for personal use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there's a script that downloads java packages from Oracle and builds a local deb repository so you can install JRE, JDK and java plugin.

https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6

```
cd ~/
wget https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6/raw/master/oab-java.sh -O oab-java.sh
chmod +x oab-java.sh
sudo ./oab-java.sh
```

For Java 7 run:

```
sudo ./oab-java.sh -7
```

The debs will be available in `/var/local/oab/deb`.

Comment: Thanks , but this is java6 which is no longer supported

Comment: sudo ./oab-java.sh -7. Updated answer.